# Caeser Shift Output

Tags: python, string, encryption

I want the output to print the string with the specified Caeser shift but my output seems to repeat the input within the output. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
# Prompt the user for a string and integer
string = input('Enter the string to encode: ')
i = int(input('Enter integer value to use: '))

# Create a for loop based on the characters in the string
# Build a new string of encoded characters based on the given rules
string= string.upper()
coded=""
for y in string:
    if y in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUCWXYZ":
        num=ord(y)
        num+=i
        if num>ord("Z"):
            num-=26
        elif num<ord("A"):
            num+=26
        coded=coded+chr(num)
    else:
        space = string.replace(" ","#")
        coded=coded+space


# Display the new string
print("Your encoded message is:",coded)
```

Comment: `space = string.replace(" ","#")` doesn't look right to me.

Comment: Two notes: you have a typo (repeated C where there should be V in your alphabet), and when I tried your program myself, it seemed to work mostly properly. Can you show the problematic input and output?

Comment: Ah, I see, it acted up when you had non-letters in the input.

Answer (score 2):

Your error occurred at `space = string.replace(" ","#")`

What's happening here is that you're getting the whole String but with characters not in the alphabet changed to `#`

To fix that, simply remove `space = string.replace(" ","#")` and change  `coded=coded+space` to `coded=coded+"#"`

```
# Prompt the user for a string and integer
string = input('Enter the string to encode: ')
i = int(input('Enter integer value to use: '))

# Create a for loop based on the characters in the string
# Build a new string of encoded characters based on the given rules
string= string.upper()
coded=""
for y in string:
    if y in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
        num=ord(y)
        num+=i
        if num>ord("Z"):
            num-=26
        elif num<ord("A"):
            num+=26
        coded=coded+chr(num)
    else:
        coded=coded+"#"


# Display the new string
print("Your encoded message is:",coded)
```

Comment: Also, changed the repeat C to V in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUCWXYZ".

Comment: This fixes the output in reference to spaces, but what about accounting for characters like ! or others? I want to omit nonalphabet characters from the output. That's why I attempted to use the replace operator on the string

Comment: If it's not an alphabetical character the else statement will cause it to be a '#'

Comment: Is there any way to omit characters not in the alphabet from the output